# Play Json: reading multiple optional nested objects

Tags: json, scala

We have a case class and Json combinators similar to the below:

```
case class Thing(param1: Option[BigDecimal],
                 param2: Option[BigDecimal])

object Thing {
  implicit val writes: Writes[Thing] = Json.writes[Thing]

  implicit val reads: Reads[Thing] = (
    (__ \ "parent" \ "param1").readNullable[BigDecimal] and
    (__ \ "param2").readNullable[BigDecimal]
    )(Thing.apply _)
```

The Json reads combinator for Thing will handle incoming Json matching the below:

```
{ 
    "parent": {
        "param1: 1111.11
     },
    "param2": 2222.22
}
```

The standard ReadNullable works as we need it to when `param1` is not present, resulting in the creation of `Thing(None, 2222.22)`.  However the `parent` object is also optional, and reading the path explicitly like the above results in a path missing exception if it does not exist.  We need this to result in a `Thing(None, 2222.22)`, the same as if the `param1` field wasn't present.

We could use a recursive read such as `(__ \\ "param1")` to bipass this exception, but ideally we would like to preserve the explicit path as there are other Json objects that have similar, if not identical fields at the same level.

Is this possible by using Json combinators in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in following way by creating two case classes.
case class Thing(param1: Option[BigDecimal])
case class ParentJson(parent: Option[Thing], param2: Option[BigDecimal])

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `.readNullable[BigDecimal]` with `read(Reads.optionNoError[BigDecimal])` to map errors to None.

Comment: There's two problems with this approach.

1)  We still need the type safety on the BigDecimal, so although this would force the field to be 'None' in the case of an error, it won't preserve the correct JSExcecption if ```param1``` wasn't a big Decimal.
2) If the ```parentObject``` object doesn't exist, it still returns a path missing exception rather than default to None